# List enumeration in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, string

Say, there are 2 tables:

```
Person
| id | name |

LanguagesSpoken
| person_id | language_name |
```

Is there a way to create a view that would contain 2 columns: `person_name` and `languages_spoken` as a comma-separated list?

I'm developing against SQLite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT p.name,
         GROUP_CONCAT(ls.language_name, ',')
    FROM PERSON p
    JOIN LANGUAGESSPOKEN ls ON ls.personid = p.personid
GROUP BY p.name
```

Reference: [SQLite aggregate functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
select name, group_concat(language_name) as languages
from person p inner join languagesSpoken l
on p.id = l.person_id
group by l.person.id
```

Answer (score 1):

group_concat() is your answer.